# Update in SQL Server causes error with unrelated field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running an update in SQL Server 2008.  The update statement is

```
UPDATE dbo.DocketEntry
SET DkePublic = 0,
    DkePrivateDocument = 1
WHERE DkeCreatedBy = 195
    AND DkePleID IN (3550, 3633);
```

When I run this statement, I get the following output in the Messages tab:

```
(11738 row(s) affected)

(11738 row(s) affected)

(11738 row(s) affected)

(11738 row(s) affected)

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'tblkey'

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'tblkey
```

... and so on

There is no tblkey column in dbo.DocketEntry.  This column was used when converting data from our legacy system.  There are a number of tables in our conversion schema which have this column (Including a conversion.DocketEntry table).  It seems like there's a bug in SQL server that throws these errors about unrelated columns.  A lot of the time it tends to refer to my tblkey column in these errors.  Any idea why I'm getting these errors and how to prevent them.

Comment: Given that you run a single `UPDATE` statement, and see multiple `(xxxx row(s) affected)` outputs before the error, I'd check to see if you have triggers firing on update of `dbo.DocketEntry`.

Comment: A bug in your code is more likely than a bug in SQL Server code, I'd say.

Comment: Have you checked for any trigger that updates another table and the column does not exist there ?

Comment: Can you please post a layout of the table including any triggers that might be associated with it? You can use:
sp_help DocketEntry

Answer (score 0):

Several tables in our database have triggers that record changes to data in the table.  This is essentially an ersatz version of Change Data Capture (CDC).  Since I was working with a test environment I simply disabled the trigger, ran my update, and enabled the trigger.  I may see if I can switch the database over to using standard Change Data Capture.  Thanks for the suggestion to look into triggers.